# How much time does Facebook need to verify my photo ID?

Tags: facebook

How much time required to complete Facebook ID verification process? I don't know why they blocked my account. I attached the copy of my id and received an automatically generated reply only. Anybody have idea about how much long is this process?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved, and how long did it take? I've waited more than a month with no reply.

Answer (score 3):

According to the answers to this question asked at the Facebook Help Center: [Why is ID verification taking so long?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1448936355413962), the time required to complete the Facebook ID verification process varies. The top answer, which was posted three months ago, recommends that you give it at least a week.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it takes from 30 minutes to 1 week. In some cases there is no response from Facebook support team for the long time (It depends on why they have blocked your account.)